# Windows 10 USB not installing on HP laptop

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, usb-boot

Laptop is a Pavillion 15 au063cl if that helps.

I had a hard drive crash so I got a new SSD, but I can't install windows or create partitions. Drive and USB stick are gpt. When I try to install windows, it says it could not be installed with error code 0x8030002. Attempts to install it as mbr just told me that the computer probably would not boot from it.

Using the command prompt to try to create a partition also fails due to "I/O error".

At this point should I install it onto the SSD via desktop and then put it back in the laptop after it's finished?

Comment: You can try but move it to the laptop before the desktop setup starts.

Comment: The first step I would take here is to update the BIOS with a bootable USB Key created from the HP Site. Try to install from the Desktop will likely create Driver compatibility issues.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? Both the drive and the USB stick are recognized as existing by the computer so I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Edit: I also might be able to salvage everything from the previous drive. Do you think copying over all files would work?

Comment: Copying what files?  You cannot boot Windows by simply copying files to another drive.

Comment: You said "Do you think copying over all files (from the old drive) would work?"  I doubt it. I think you have a driver problem and that is why I suggested updating the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: BIOS update did nothing to help it. It gives me the same error code and trying to clean the disk or create partitions  causes it to tell me that there is a fatal hardware error.